# Web forwarding breaks jQuery animate on mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-animate, vertical-scrolling, jquery-scrollable

I have been working on a site that has a link at the bottom that animates back to the top of the page when clicked. The site worked fine before I set up web forwarding with Network Solutions. Now clicking on the link works on desktop, but not on mobile devices (iPad, iPhone, HTC One S tested). It appears that the web forwarding has added extra HTML to the document. I was wondering if anybody had experience with web forwarding breaking jQuery on mobile.

This is my jQuery.

```
      $('#scroll a').click(function(){
          $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
          }, 800);
          return false;
      });
```

And this is the HTML added by web forwarding.

```
<html>
 <frameset rows="100%" ,="" *"="" border="0" frameborder="0" screen_capture_injected="true">
  <frame src="http://hostingdomain.com/subfolder/index.html" name="WEBSITENAME.COM">
   #document
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">...</html>
  </frame>
 </frameset>
</html>
```

Any thoughts on getting the jQuery to work on mobile devices?